# Windows 8 doesn't boot: Error 0x0000000e

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

My Windows 8 does not boot. I get the error 0x0000000e. I already tried to fix the MBR with this [tutorial](http://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/):

Every time I run `bcdedit.exe /create` or `bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd` I get the error

```
Requested system device cannot be found
```

I can't reinstall Windows 8 because I only have the upgrade version and I don't have the key of my old Windows XP OEM version. So I can't activate Windows 8 if I would reinstall it.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: why not boot a recovery partition if you have one? or a recovery disc?

Comment: Windows XP and 8 are completely incompatible so when you do an "upgrade" install it will do a completely clean install anyway. You should have a separate key for Win 8. This was the same as of Vista onwards...

Comment: actually the problem is solved beacause i found an xp key. anywas i have a seperate win 8 key but if you activate it without having xp or higher installed previously you get an error.